# Restrict dimensions of cables

Tags: constraints

I am creating an animated manual for a device that has an external cable connected to it. The cable has a length (1m) and a diameter.
When I bend the cable, I would like to ensure that the length always remains the same. That means, the total length of the cable should always be 1m.
I use a BezierCurve bevelled with a circle. So the length of the BezierCurve has to be limited. 
Is there a way to apply such a constraint to a BezierCurve?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance

Answer (score 5):

I think it would be better to use tesselated cylinder with Curve modifier, length of cylinder remains constant, just modify bezier shape.